# Is there a way to receive suggestions by other users to me so in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord.py. I want that users make suggestions in their server itself and the suggestions reach me. I have no clue if this is possible and how is it possible. Please consider helping me out. Until now I only have the code for the normal suggestion command which works completely

```
@client.command()
    async def suggest(self, ctx, *,suggestion):

        
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name = 'suggestions')

        suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(colour = 0xFF0000)
        suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'Suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
        suggestEmbed.add_field(name = 'New suggestion!', value = f'{suggestion}')

        message = await ctx.send(embed=suggestEmbed)

        await message.add_reaction('✅')
        await message.add_reaction('❌')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are the owner of the bot. you can get your id with `bot.owner_id`.

```py
async def suggest(self, ctx, *, suggestion):
     #make embed here
     owner = self.bot.get_user(self.bot.owner_id)
     await owner.send(embed=embed)
```

if `get_user` doesn't work

```py
async def suggest(self, ctx, *, suggestion):
     #make embed here
     owner = await self.bot.fetch_user(self.bot.owner_id)
     await owner.send(embed=embed)
```

If you are not the owner of the bot, just hardcode your id in the get_user

### References:

- [bot.owner_id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20owner#discord.ext.commands.Bot.owner_id)
- [get_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_user)

Comment: small problem: get_user is not a coroutine, it shouldn’t be awaited

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will be more careful next time

Comment: await owner.send does not work, so what should I use? The error is
```Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: This is the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user%20send#discord.User.send) I referred to, does it raise an error, you probably have your dms closed then

Comment: try printing `owner`. I edited my question when Lukas pointed out an error, have you seen the edited version?

Comment: I see this
`async def suggest(self, ctx, *, suggestion):
     #make embed here
     owner = self.bot.get_user(self.bot.owner_id)
     await owner.send(embed=embed)
`

Comment: Have you tried hard coding your id into the `get_user`?

Comment: I am the owner of the bot so I guess I don't need to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230061/discussion-between-ceres-and-chaoticnebula).

Comment: For the error in the owner_id thing a few reasons are possible:
1. Your client isn't a bot, just a discord.Client. According to the docs, a client has no attribute owner_id [discord.py Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client)
2. The owner of the bot is not set. More about you find [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.owner_id) in the discord.py docs